# Como cambiar la contraseña de LDAP

Tags: ldap

Estoy tratando de cambiar la contraseña de LDAP, ya que cuando introduzco la contraseña me saca el siguiente mensaje de error:

Enter LDAP Password:

ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

La contraseña que he usado es 1234 sin embargo ya he ido al fichero de configuración de LDAP y como sospechaba estaba encriptada en base64.

Por ello no se como cambiar la contraseña ya que he intentado volver a reinstalarlo y no me vuelve a pedir la contraseña de LDAP ya que creo que la guarda en caché, por ello si alguien sabe algo agradecería la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución parcial, si tienes muchas cosas o similar en LDAP, te recomiendo NO seguir esta solución.

Lo primero que he hecho ha sido cambiar al usuario root, después he hecho:

apt purge slapd  //ATENCIÓN CON ESTO ya que te eliminará todo lo que tengas de slapd junto con sus configuraciones

Y a continuación he hecho:

apt purge ldap-utils //ldap-utils por lo que tengo entendido es donde se almacena todo usuarios, contraseñas, etc... Entonces al borrar ldap-utils se borraría todo

SIN EMBARGO y tenéis que tener en cuenta lo siguiente que si no borráis slapd, ldap-utils seguirá igual, no entiendo el por que pero lo he probado a borrar solo el utils y me seguía igual así que al borrar ambos me ha dejado volver a introducir la contraseña nueva al volver a instalar el ldap

Os dejo el comando para volver a instalarlo y así que os pida la nueva contraseña:

sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils

Recordad que también tenéis que volver a reconfigurar el slapd os dejo el comando para esto:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd